# Service Throttling ability in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to achieve the service  throttling ability to the rest services in Spring, particular with Spring boot.

**The Expectation here is:** My services are exposed to outside world, currently there are no restrictions on the number of service calls per second/min. We want to control this by putting the throttling limit.

- I have an alternative option, by tracking the requests in concurrent Hash Map or any caching mechanism.

But more interested in the way spring in considering this. I know that i can be able to do it in **node.js / scala**

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634868/restrict-access-to-public-service-many-times#comment66574270_39634868).

Comment: Thanks Manish and shmosel.

Comment: It will be great if you can post some pointer to some examples to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a fairly new opensource project which handles this:

https://github.com/shlomokoren/spring-boot-throttling

> Declarative approach of throttling control over the Spring services.
> @Throttling annotation helps you to limit the number of service method
> calls per java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit for a particular user, IP
> address, HTTP header/cookie value, or using Spring Expression Language
> (SpEL).

Comment: how can I use it as the filter ? Instead of writing the same code for all rest controllers

Comment: this solution requires java8+

Comment: Repo does not exists any more in github

Comment: I have updated the URL to the current github repo